# Disable Data connection automatically

Tags: 2.2-froyo, data-connection, automation

I own an Optimus One. I want the Data Connection to go off, everytime I lock the keypad. For that, now, I manually go to Setting--> Wireless & networks--> Mobile Networks--> Data Enable.

Is there any way to automatically disable the data when the keypad is locked(or phone is in sleep mode) and enable it when the phone wakes up?

Also, I can't find Mozilla Firefox in my app store. Why it's so?

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to use some sort of 3rd party program like [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), [Locale](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.twofortyfouram.locale) or [AutomateIt](https://market.android.com/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage).

These programs allow you to set triggers such as:

- starting an app
- screen on/off
- connected to Wi-fi
- location
- etc...

and perform actions based on that, such as:

- toggle data
- toggle GPS
- run an app
- etc...